# Check if List of Tuples of Strings appear in string in order

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a list of Tuples that contain combinations of strings that I want to check for in a Queue property of my text file object (newFile). The Queue is a queue of strings called Lines.

I'm not sure the list of Tuples is the way to go but I only want a true result if Item1 and Item2 of any Tuple are found (in Item1 then Item2 order) in any line. Here's my best shot and I just can't figure out how to write the LINQ statement.

```
List<Tuple<string,string>> codes = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
   {
      new Tuple<string, string>("01,", "02,"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("02,", "03,"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("03,", "88,"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("88,", "88,"),
      new Tuple<string, string>("89,", "90,")                 
   };

bool codesFound = newFile.Lines
                      .Any(Regex.Match(codes.Select(x => (x.Item1 + "(.*)" + x.Item2)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you want to check the regex way, here you are:

```
bool codesFound = newFile.Lines.Any(p =>
              Regex.IsMatch(p, string.Join("|", codes.Select(x => x.Item1 + ".+" + x.Item2).ToList()))
              );
```

Here, I join all patterns into a single string like `01,.+02,|02,.+03,`... and then check if there is any string in the input array that satisfies this condition.

Comment: Nice. So the pipe character is regex for OR? Is that how that works?

Comment: Yes, the pipe stands for OR. Also, `.*` can be replace with `.+` in case there should be some text between `Item1` and `Item2`.

Comment: Thanks. There will always be some text between the two. Should I use .+ instead of .* ?

Comment: `.*`  means `any character, 0 or more repetitions`. `.+` means `any character, 1 or more repetitions`. So, if there MUST be some text in between, you will need to use `.+`. I updated the answer.

Comment: What if I needed a minimum of say 10 characters between Item1 and Item2?

Comment: It is easy: `.{10,}` means `any character, minimum 10 repetitions`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you the result you're after:

```
bool found = newFile.Lines
    .Any(x => codes.Select(y => x.IndexOf(y.Item1) > -1 && x.IndexOf(y.Item2) > -1 
                            && x.IndexOf(y.Item1) < x.IndexOf(y.Item2)).Any(z => z));
```

Comment: Amazing. So x represents one of the lines and y represents one of the Tuples and 1) we check for the existence of both Items and 2) that Item1 comes before Item2. So the z is where we are saying if the foregoing returns true anytime return true?